# How do I get svg code from an svg image url?

Tags: html, url, svg

So i have a url with an svg image, I need to save the svg locally so I don't need to make requests every time I need the image.How do I get the svg code?
For example this url: https://guidedprojects.dev/assets/files/star_full-50258ff83d0a0d79ee884ed5642ce931.svg

Comment: View page source from your browser, copy the contents, paste the contents into a text file, save it as an svg file. Or you could save page as.

Comment: Just stick view-source: in front of the URL i.e. `view-source:https://guidedprojects.dev/assets/files/star_full-50258ff83d0a0d79ee884ed5642ce931.svg`

Comment: Do you mean you have a LARGE SVG and the network access is noticeably slow? And the SVG doesn't change so you want to save the SVG once (like in localStorage) and then use that stored version?